# How to undo SVN changes..?

Tags: svn

I'm finding lots of similar questions, but nothing exactly like this so I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I'm just trying to update the readme.txt file in a [tagged version of my WordPress plugin](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/paypal-for-woocommerce/tags/1.1.5/).  I wasn't thinking correctly, and I ran the following commands.

```
svn up
svn cp trunk tags/1.1.5
```

I was thinking it would just take any new/modified files in the trunk directory (which in this case would only be that one file) and copy it into my tagged version directory.  Instead, it copied the entire /trunk directory into my tagged version directory, so when I would run svn stat I would get this.

```
A + tags\1.1.5\trunk
A + tags\1.1.5\trunk\readme.txt
```

And when I look at the local directory I can see that new directory was in there, but that's not what I wanted, of course.

At this point I just deleted that directory back out via my file browser, and now when I run svn stat I end up with a whole bunch lines like this...

```
! tags\1.1.5\trunk
! tags\1.1.5\trunk\assets
```

I have a line like that for every file/directory that was deleted, which makes sense, but now I'm just a little scared to continue.  I really don't know SVN very well, and the only time I ever use it is when I'm updating WP plugins, which really isn't that often.

Anyway, I haven't run svn ci, so the updates weren't pushed to the remote SVN repo yet, but I'd like to get my local stuff back to the way it was before I ever made that original copy mistake.  I tried svn revert trunk, but that doesn't seem to have done anything at all. I also tried svn revert tags\1.1.5 and that gave me a message **Skipped 'tags1.1.5'** and doesn't seem to have actually done anything.

Any information about how I can simply undo everything I've done here, or what the best procedure is to fix my screw up here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your post, your mentioned tags- and trunk directories are working copies.
You said you didn't commit it yet. So you could delete your complete tags-directory not only tags/1.1.5 using your file browser and then check it out again.

PS:
svn information is in version > 1.7 in the root directory of your working copy. So deleting 1.1.5 causes svn to tell you it's missing it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your PS there..??  So you're basically saying I can just delete my entire /tags directory...how do I checkout again?  Is that what the svn up command does for me?  Kinda makes me feel like if I delete that whole thing then I'll just end up with even more deleted file/folder lines, no..??

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be what's happening.  I moved the tags folder to another place outside the local repo, and then when I run svn stat I see a line for every single file/folder deleted for every tag I've ever had.  I just want to get back to where it doesn't see any deletes at all, because really, that's where I am this point had I not made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
svn revert -R tags
```